# access AWS elastic ip with https

Tags: django, ssl, amazon-ec2

I am trying to connect facebook app with my web app ( Django ). My app is currently on AWS and i havent setup a domain name yet . I am using elastic IP to access my website.

I learned about installing certificates, etc but nothing seems to be working fine.

My requirement : I want to access my elastic IP with https://
Please help

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is NO. You have to buy a domain name.

You can read the gritty details [here](https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/Guidance-Deprecated-Internal-Names.pdf)

You can read the friendly GoDaddy version [here](https://www.godaddy.com/help/can-i-request-a-certificate-for-an-intranet-name-or-ip-address-6935)

But the sum of it is:

> Effective October 1, 2016, Certification Authorities (CAs) must revoke SSL certificates that use intranet names or IP addresses.

So, just buy a domain name. They are cheap. You can even buy one directly from [AWS Route 53](https://console.aws.amazon.com/route53/home)

Comment: Thanks, How about accessing xxxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com ?

Comment: I suppose if you could get a certificate authority to issue you a cert for amazonaws.com but I doubt it. You could just generate a self signed cert and if only you are using it you can easily force your browser to accept it.